# On the closedness of KdV operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Some papers that I am currently reading state that the classical KdV operator $Au=u'+u'''$ with 
$D(A)=\{u\in H^3(0,1)|u(0)=u(1)=u'(1)=0\}$ 
is a closed operator in $L^2(0,1)?$ However, no proof is given. How do I show this fact?

Comment: hmm the problem is bounding the $L^2$ norm for the second derivative. Is it possible that you also have $u'(0)=0$? Then I would have a solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, $u'(0)=0$ is not a condition in the domain of $A$. The given conditions indeed come from classical boundary conditions when KdV is posed on a finite interval.

Comment: i guess you could already show that $A$ with $\{f \in L^2 : Af \in L^2\}$ as domain is closed. Then it is left to show $D(A)$ is closed in $\{f \in L^2 : Af \in L^2\}$ w.r.t. the graph norm of $A$. Is this where you got stuck?

Comment: Can you share the papers mentioning this claim ?

Comment: It is stated in Proposition 3.1 in Rosier's paper "Exact boundary controllability for the Korteweg-de Vries equation on a bounded domain, ESAIM Control Optim. Calc. Var., 2 (1997) 33–55"

Comment: It is also stated in Coron's paper "Gevrey Class Regularity of a Semigroup Associated with a Nonlinear Korteweg-de Vries Equation"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with an answer which uses the sequential definition of closedness. It can be done via a compactness argument but thanks anyway for the effort.